# With jFace and SWT, is it preferable to have the Gui Thread as the main thread or that does not matter?

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, swt, jface, ui-thread

More specifically, my application is a network application, a kind of hub in which different endpoint connect and communicate. We need a graphical user interface to monitor the behavior of the participant to the hub, and etc....

Provided of course that the appropriate communication between thread is applied such that for updating the UI thread from another thread etc... does it matter that the GUI thread is the main thread or not.

Up until now, my Gui thread was a separate thread launch from my main thread. However a colleague told me that it was wrong.

Does anyone has some lessons learned or best practice that you could share with me on that subject ?

Many thanks

Maat

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "the main thread"?

1. If you mean "the thread which calls `main` method", it doesn't matter.
2. If you mean "the thread which does important work for the application", it should definitely not be the same as GUI thread (which should never run any long-running methods or wait for anything except GUI events).

Comment: Alright many thanks. Got it. In any case as of now, I put my Gui in the main thread, and launch the rest in other thread. Yes the Thread with the main.